# How can I change the value of a morsel of a cookie in a python CookieJar?

Tags: python, cookies

I need to change a couple of attributes of cookies that I get from a post response, but I can't reference the cookie in the CookieJar. How can I do this?

Having read the docs, `pop` only gives the value, whereas I need to change things like the httponly field and the value, and referencing by the name only gives me the value, not the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I found to do this was to do

```
for cookie in my_cookie_jar:
    if cookie <is the cookie I want, eg cookie.name == my_cookie_name>:
        cookie.<morsel> = new_value
        my_cookie_jar.pop(cookie.name)  # removes cookie from my_cookie_jar
        my_cookie_jar.set_cookie(cookie)  # adds it back in
```

Hey presto. Clearly extend the CookieJar class and add this to it to make it neat.

Comment: If you know the name of the cookie, why do you iterate the jar? IOW, `c = jar.pop(cookie_name); c.morsel = new_value; jar.set_cookie(c)`

Comment: Good question; however the issue is that `pop` returns the name of the cookie only, not the cookie. So you have to get the cookie from iterating the jar first, and then change it and pop it. However I am very open to better solutions.

Comment: Just realised I wrote "...returns the name of the cookie..." which should read "...returns the value of the cookie...".

Comment: I just did `cookie.value = new_value`
And it is unnecessary to pop cookie and set it back.